# NSI Textbox on custom page doe not appear on page display but appear on move over

Tags: nsis

On a custom page, when the page display the border and background color of the textbox.

When the user foce the page to reprint (losing focus our hover on one of the textbox), the textbox are displayed on the page.

NOTE: the custom page was created using HM NIS Edit V2.0.3 and the installer is compiled using MakeNSISW 2.3.3.

Comment: Please post the relevant code. Telling use the version of MakeNSISW is pointless, tell us the version of NSIS itself (probably 2.46, 2.51 or 3.0)

Answer (score 0):

I had 2 things wrong:

- Overlapping controls. The label where going on top of the text box.
- The controls need to be inside of a group box otherwiste it seem that printing does not work properly.